# For BFS, is setting a visited variable as list of bool faster than just a set?

Tags: python

Sometimes in BFS algorithms and more, you'll have a "visited" variable to keep track of nodes that have been visited. Does anyone know if it's faster to just initialize this variable to a list of False and set each index to true after being visited, or if it's faster to just set it to a set and check if elements are in it?

Comment: If you want to check if an object is present in the set, your efficiency is constant time O(1). So definitely faster than a list. List is O(n) if you want to check if an index is present in it.

Comment: @Goion Actually, checking if an index is present in it is equivalent to check if the boolean at an index is true (since it's a list of booleans), so it's O(1).

Comment: The list in python is linked list right? So the efficiency of get value at index n will be O(n). Correct me if I am wrong. @enzo

Comment: Nvm. It is not linked list.

Comment: @Goion Yes, [it's an array list](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list) so it'll be O(1). I think in this case they are technically equivalent, but I don't know if there are any more differences apart.

Comment: @enzo well checking if an element is present takes O(n) for a list, which is different from getting/setting the element at a known index, so I'm wondering if there's a speed diff between getting/setting and checking if in?